# Asp.net using data binding expression with int

Tags: asp.net, bind

I have a table called Quotation with a column called Gross_Total of type Int. When I use the Bind method to bind it to  gridview colunm like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gross_Total") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I get a long runtime error:

> DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType015[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable1[[System.Int32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, Pu...' does not contain a property with the name
>   'Gross_Total'.

My data binding method:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MajesticEntities majesticentities = new MajesticEntities();
        var query = majesticentities.Quotations
                    .Select(quote => new
                    {
                        quote.Id,
                        quote.Bank,
                        quote.Customer.First_name,
                        quote.Customer.Surname,
                        quote.CPR,
                        quote.Car.Maker,
                        quote.Car.Type,
                        quote.Down_Payment,
                        quote.Gross_Total,
                        quote.Balance,
                        quote.Installments,
                        quote.Bank_Employee,
                        quote.Status_Bank,
                        quote.Notes_Bank,
                        quote.Status_Invoice,
                        quote.Notes_Invoice
                    });
        gridSample.DataSource = query.ToList();
        gridSample.DataBind();

        var query2 = from b in majesticentities.Banks
                     select b.Name;
        DropDownListBanks.DataSource = query2.ToList();
        DropDownListBanks.DataBind();
    }
```

Update:

Grid view source code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridSample" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" ForeColor="#99ccff" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEdit" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument=""> 
                             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/document_edit.png" Height="50px" Width="50px"/> </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkInsert" runat="server" Text="" ValidationGroup="editGrp" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />     <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png"/> </asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkCancel" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="CancelNew" CommandArgument="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/back-2-1.png" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ref">
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuotationId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                               ValidationGroup="editGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CPR">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CPR") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Car">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCarMaker" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Maker") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCarType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gross_Total") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Down Payment">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDownPayment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Down_Payment") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Balance">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBalance" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Balance") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bank">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBank" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Bank") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Check your anonymous data source object. It doesn't seem to have the Gross_Total property.

Comment: didn't know it uses the anonymous type. thought it fetches the values form the database tables directly. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share your databinding method?

Comment: Something's wrong with data binding. It displays each column  twice.

Comment: please also post your gridview html.

Comment: added it as update to the question

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was away. Why do you have all the columns as TemplateFields? It is not necessary. Columns that you don't edit in the grid can remain BoundFileds. Other than that I don't see why it would duplicate the columns. Secondly, you can leave the gridview as is but change the non-editable columns from Bind to Eval.

Comment: autogeneratecolumn property of the grid view was missing. I set it to false and it works fine now

Comment: That was exactly what I was gonna write as soon as I had the to get back to my computer. :)